# Php artisan storage:link delete stored files (DigitalOcean)

Tags: php, heroku, digital-ocean

The case: I Upload a Laravel project on DigitalOcean with the next commands In Yaml file

```
run_command: |- 
php artisan migrate --force
php artisan storage:link
heroku-php-apache2 public/
```

The issue: Every deployment, these commands are being run and the storage files are deleted. How can I deploy without deleting uploaded files?

additional info:-
1- Table records are not deleted Just the uploaded files
2- imagePath: base_url/storage/images/products/imageName.png

Comment: What does this line do `heroku-php-apache2 public/`? `php artisan storage:link` creates an symlink from storage/public/ to public/storage so if that line deletes public files it gets deleted.

Comment: 1- heroku command used for deploy Laravel on heroku server
2- If I removed the command of storage:link how can I get the images link which it is something like: base_url/storage/images/products/2/image.png

Answer (score 0):

The Solution: It's not an issue. the problem is every deployment, DigitalOcean deploys every time on a different server (Container) so It's like a new device. but tables are not cleared just storage stuff

Answer (score -1):

I fix this problem with this command

```
cd public/ && ln -s ../storage/app/public storage && cd ..
```

make sure your storage folder is not .gitignore
got to .gitignore remove public/storage